# Execute sql server script from java

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using `sql server`, my issue is when I change any stored procedure or database table changes I need to make track of it and need to update it on each and every server when my related java code is uploaded.

So I am finding something tool or something if possible with java code that if I give stored procedure or database changes file(i.e .sql file) it executes it on sql server.

May be my question is silly but I really want to know about is this possible with any tool or through code?

Comment: You should rather use Liquibase or Flyway to manage your schema migration scripts

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the scenario would be:

1. Read .sql file using one of the [Readers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)
2. Execute SQL commands using [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) class.

Comment: We can not alter procedure using statement class