# Executing mssql procedure from file in java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute procedures stored in a file into MSSQL database using Java code. Currently I'm executing the procedure codes manually. I need to automate this process using Java. How can i achieve this?

Comment: What kind of file are you storing your procedures in?

Comment: procedure codes are stored in file with extension '.sql'

Comment: you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113674/how-do-i-execute-a-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-java-jsp-returning-table-d)? Or you can also see [Radek's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18531198/5588347).

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].